# urlopen doesn't work to connect to website

Tags: python, anaconda

Just learning to code using python and trying some basic web scraping. I've installed python 3.9 and Anaconda on my system as well as installed a few pip libraries.

Here's my code:

```
# Import requests (to download the page)
#pip install requests
import requests
import urllib3

# Import BeautifulSoup (to parse what we download)
#pip install BeautifulSoup4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'http://google.com')
page_html = r.read()
r = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

print(r)
```

However, here's the error I'm getting:

```
Blank (literally blank line)
[Finished in 0.9s]
```

Any help would be appreciated! I've been googling for a few hours to no avail..

Comment: Hi Kzoo. You are importing `urllib3` but then using urlopen from `urllib`. Try using the example on this page: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Okay I instead imported urllib (not 3) and same error

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the link! I just tried that example and all it says is [Finished in 0.6s]. There isn't actually an output?

Comment: Update: Here's the new code I'm trying but still no output... just says Finished in 0.9s

Comment: Make sure you are printing out the data

Comment: When I print(r.h1) or print(r) it just says "None" or is blank then says Finished in 0.9s?

Comment: Can you edit your original question to include the updated code so I can test it?

Comment: Done :) Thanks! Didn't realize I could edit the original question!

Comment: Ultimately I'm trying to use other websites and get the complete HTML output and then do some keyword searches on them :)

Comment: r.read() isn't giving you anything, To get the raw HTML you can use `r.data.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: With that change I now get the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 46480: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

try it :

```
from six.moves import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
r = urllib.request.urlopen('https://google.com')

s = soup(r, "html.parser")

print(s)
```

upd:

its runs fine here and on repl web site.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This gives me this error: can't find '__main__' module in ''

Comment: look print in my upd

Comment: Thanks Jasar! I'm not familiar with all of this stuff quite yet :) Is there some setting, PATH file, or some library I'm missing for it not to work on my PC?

Comment: For example, here is the entire error code. It looks like it's not looking in the right spot? C:\Users\Kendrick\anaconda3\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in ''
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u ""]
[dir: C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\Kendrick\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA

Comment: @KzooKendrick the problem is in your windows installation. use conda enviroment or try to use a linux for tests